# "Iteration limit reached at time" when i try to simulate my code

Tags: algorithm, iteration, vhdl, limit

**I'm trying to implement Booth Algorithm in VHDL, already run a "paper test" and the code apparently works but when I simulate it I'm not getting the desire results... Then I replace the code to do an A-Shift to test but when I simulate my code I'm getting this error:**

*Error (suppressible): (vsim-3601) Iteration limit 5000 reached at time 180 ns.*

**I just replace this line:** `P := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(P) SRA 1);`

**For this:** `P := P(16) & P(16 downto 1);`

**This is the code atm:**

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY algor_booth IS
    PORT(oper1 :  IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
         oper2 :  IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
         sel :    IN STD_LOGIC;
         result : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
            );
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE algor OF algor_booth IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS (sel)
        VARIABLE A, S, P: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 DOWNTO 0);
        VARIABLE Ma2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        --VARIABLE flag: STD_LOGIC;
    BEGIN

        IF sel = '0' THEN
            Ma2 := (NOT oper1) + 1;
            A   := oper1 & "00000000" & '0';
            S   := Ma2 & "00000000" & '0';
            P   := "00000000" & oper2 & '0';
        ELSE
            --flag := '0';
            FOR i IN 1 TO 8 LOOP
                IF P(1 DOWNTO 0) = "01" THEN
                    P := P + A;
                    --flag := '0';
                    --P(17) := flag;
                ELSIF P(1 DOWNTO 0) = "10" THEN
                    P := P + S;
                    --flag := '1';
                    --P(17) := flag;
                END IF;
                --P(17) := flag;
                P :=    P(16) & P(16 downto 1);
                --P(17) := flag;
            END LOOP;
            result <= P(16 DOWNTO 1);

        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END algor;
```

Comment: Find and eliminate the combinatorial loop.

Comment: The loop works, the problem starts when I do the change described above.

Comment: I analyzed, elaborated and simulated your code after converting it to use package numeric_std instead of Synopsys' std_logic_unsigned. Had the iteration limit set to 5000 and no error. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (include your testbench). Didn't validate your algorithm.

Comment: There is no loop inside this module that can run for 5000 iterations itself, so the error arise as a result of interaction with code outside this module.  Please make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, as also suggested by user1155120.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**After trying a lot, just changed this line:** `P := P(16) & P(16 downto 1);`

**For this one:** `P(16 downto 0) := P(17 downto 1);`

**And problem solved!**

**Here is the fixed code:**

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY algor_booth IS
    PORT(oper1 :  IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
         oper2 :  IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
         sel :    IN STD_LOGIC;
         result : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
            );
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE algor OF algor_booth IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS (oper1, oper2)
        VARIABLE A, S, P: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
        VARIABLE Ma2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        VARIABLE flag: STD_LOGIC;
    BEGIN
            Ma2 := (NOT oper1) + 1;
            A   := '0' & oper1 & "00000000" & '0';
            S   := '0' & Ma2 & "00000000" & '0';
            P   := '0' & "00000000" & oper2 & '0';  
            flag := '0';

            FOR i IN 1 TO 8 LOOP
                IF (P(1) = '0' AND P(0) = '1') THEN
                    flag := '0';
                    P(17) := flag;
                          P := P + A;
                ELSIF (P(1) = '1' AND P(0) = '0') THEN
                    flag := '1';
                    P(17) := flag;
                          P := P + S;
                END IF;
                P(17) := flag;
                P(16 downto 0) := P(17 downto 1);
                P(17) := flag;
            END LOOP;
            result <= P(16 DOWNTO 1);
    END PROCESS;
END algor;
```

**Thanks for your help guys!**

Comment: Looking at the two versions of your code there's nothing explaining the problem or the fix here.  Looking in a Modelsim User's Manual we find this is a zero time loop, meaning an interaction between your unseen testbench and your design model, which you've adjusted to eliminate the problem. The question and answer are not useful to other Stackoverflow readers without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example demonstrating the problem and the solution.